# Unable to pass initial state through createStore in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to pass initial state in createStore but, it is showing me error/warning in console.

`Unexpected key "blogList" found in initialState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "routing". Unexpected keys will be ignored.`

Along with this error i am not getting initial data in store state. 
From the docs : 
[initialState] (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. **If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.**

Is there anything i am missing ? i am just logging state for now. and its not happening right now. I have referred these videos to learn redux [here.](https://learnredux.com/)

Here is my store code :

```
var Redux = require('redux');
var syncHistoryWithStore = require('react-router-redux').syncHistoryWithStore;
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;
var rootReducer = require('../reducers/index');
//var BlogActions = require('./actions/actions.js');
var blogList = {
  "id":1,
  "heading": "Heading of blogpost : No topic suggested",
  "cardText": "Content of this blogpost is temporary and will be gathered from Server later. Also Reflux is yet to be implemented",
  "date": "16 July, 2016",
  "tags": ["general","react","firstpost"],
  "content": "sample text"
};

var defaultState = {
  blogList: blogList
};

var BlogStore = Redux.createStore( rootReducer, defaultState);
var history = syncHistoryWithStore( browserHistory, BlogStore);

module.exports =  { "store" : BlogStore, "history" : history };
```

Root reducer :

```
var combineReducers = require('redux').combineReducers;
var routerReducer = require('react-router-redux').routerReducer;
var blogList = require('./blogList');
var rootReducer = combineReducers({blogList:blogList,routing:routerReducer});
module.exports = rootReducer;
```

BlogList Reducer :

```
function blogList (state, action) {
console.log(action,state);
return state;
}

module.export =  blogList;
```

P.S. : I am using React Router along with redux. and i can see routing in store.getState from react dev tools.

Comment: if you debug var blogList in your rootReducer file is it defined?

Comment: @The Brofessor , Thanks for the tip. blogList is defined in rootReducer but it empty object ( typeof blogList === object ). However for rootReducer it is function. Am i exporting it in wrong way ?

Comment: @The Brofessor, I have moved function directly with root reducer and it worked. i believe error should be due to export.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its a typo and the last line of the blogList file should be `module.exports` rather than `module.export`.